# What to do when the variable that enters :src becomes null?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

What to do when the variable that enters :src becomes null?

```
<v-img
  :src="product.eyecatch"
  :lazy-src="product.eyecatch"
></v-img>
```

When product.eyecatch is null, the following error is displayed

「Cannot read property 'src' of null」

What should i do? Is there no choice but to make product.eyecatch nullable?

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to happen when the value is `null`?

Comment: If null, I don't want to display any image.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use the ternary if inside the :src

Example:

```
<v-img
  :src="product.eyecatch ? product.eyecatch : ''"
  :lazy-src="product.eyecatch"
></v-img>
```

Or use the

```
v-if
v-else
```

when declaring the v-img

Comment: it is perfect! Dealed with v-if! Thank you!

Comment: That's perfect. Mark as correct so anyone else who deals with the same situation get's the desired help. Or maybe upvote it. @KoutaNakamura :))

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `v-if`, you shound not get this error anymore, as the component won't get rendered if the `product.eyecatch` is null

```
<v-img
  v-if="product.eyecatch"
  :src="product.eyecatch"
  :lazy-src="product.eyecatch"
></v-img>
```

Comment: @KoutaNakamura Remember to mark the answer as correct if it helped you solve your case. I'm glad it worked out